# Importing JSON into CodeIgniter

Tags: php, python, json, codeigniter

How do I import and use JSON in CodeIgniter? For example, the codesnippet below is written in Python and converts [Reddit's front page](http://www.reddit.com/.json) into JSON and prints the keys:

```
reddit_front = r"""{"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "", "children": ...  """

import json
j = json.loads(reddit_front)
print j.keys()
```

Comment: I believe php provides you with json_encode and json_Decode functions to deal with json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a json string ready you can use below function in php to read json string.

```
$result is the json string for example

$res = json_decode($result,true);
```

Now use foreach to loop through the $res to print the values

Comment: Hi Venkat. Entelo is my favorite for freelancing: (http://www.entelo.com/). Here are some more really useful places for design and development freelancers: (http://99designs.com/) , (http://www.topcoder.com/)

Comment: How Blogging Can Help In Career Development For A Software Engineer? (dzone.com/NOEW)